# About replacing period with emdash and aligning caption to figure border

Tags: floats, captions

This is about `caption` package. I read the well-written [manual of this package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption?lang=en) (but not thoroughly, because I am new to LaTex) and found not enough about number(s) associated with caption label. So,

1. How one can substitute the period between chapter and figure numbers with a custom symbol, say an emdash (i.e. as **FIGURE 7—1** and without `\renewcommand`)?
2. Likewise, what about putting a custom symbol right before caption number, something like **FIGURE P7—1**?

And the third question about caption alignment,

3. Is it possible to align the caption with figure borders (here I mean left border)? How?

---

This is a typical MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionStyle{mystyle}[]{
        name=FIGURE,
        labelsep=newline
        }

\setcounter{chapter}{7}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=10cm]{testimage}
        \captionsetup{style=mystyle}
        \caption{Caption of my figure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And the output,

[image]

---

Of course I read those questions about using emdash instead of period or caption alignment, but if possible I like to use `amsmath` and `caption` package only.

Comment: `\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{emdash}{\textemdash}` for example for the `emdash` feature ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I appreciate your comment and previous answer, but this put the emdash as a label separator not between chapter and figure numbers.

Comment: Well, I deleted my answer. It was an error of course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you want the references to be printed.

If you want that the reference to figure or table 7–1 is printed as “7.1”, here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{pcdn}{% Prefix Chapter Dash Number
  \MakeUppercase{#1} P\arabic{chapter}--\arabic{\@captype}%
}
\makeatother

\DeclareCaptionStyle{mystyle}{
  labelformat=pcdn,
  labelsep=newline
}

\setcounter{chapter}{7}

\begin{document}

We see in figure~\ref{ei}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\captionsetup{style=mystyle}

\centering

\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Caption of my figure}\label{ei}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `caption` package allows defining various formats; in this case we want to change the format for the label (by default “Figure *n*” or “Table *n*”, where *n* is the number). In the second argument to `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` one can use `#1` that stands for the appropriate environment name and `#2` for the value of the associated counter. Since we want the label in uppercase, `\MakeUppercase{#1}` is the obvious choice. However since the number should be typeset in a special way, detached from the reference, we can use explicitly the counters, so `P\arabic{chapter}--\arabic{figure}` might seem the good choice; we can do better, though: in a float environment, `\@captype` stands either for `figure` or for `table`, so `\arabic{\@captype}` will expand to the needed counter. Since we're using a command with `@` in its name, the code must be surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, see [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351).

---

If the reference should be “P7–1” just like in the caption, the code can be simpler.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{pcdn}{\MakeUppercase{#1} #2}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{P\arabic{chapter}--\arabic{figure}}

\DeclareCaptionStyle{mystyle}{
  labelformat=pcdn,
  labelsep=newline
}

\setcounter{chapter}{7}

\begin{document}

We see in figure~\ref{ei}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\captionsetup{style=mystyle}

\centering

\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Caption of my figure}\label{ei}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of the `minipage`one could use `\captionbox{`<caption>`}{`<content>`}` as an alternative.

Comment: Yes this is exactly the solution I was looking for. Could you please direct me to an intermediate-level reference on `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` used above? I don't see what they do. Is that a kind of hacking the `caption` package?

Comment: @Shaqpad The standard reference is [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351); I'll add some comments to the first solution later.